# Online Boutique Extensions

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have been working on extending the GCP [Online Boutique](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo) microservices example, and I would like to add [Istio AuthorizationPolicy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/) resources to the system.

Concretely, I want an `AuthorizationPolicy` to block all not-whitelisted traffic to `cartservice`, and I want to whitelist traffic from `frontend` to `cartservice`.

Currently, I am able to block traffic with an `AuthorizationPolicy`, but I cannot whitelist traffic by principal or namespace.

For context, here is my system setup. (Anything not explicitly stated here is the default from the demo linked above)

*Istio Version:*

```
$ istioctl version
client version: 1.4.6
control plane version: 1.4.6-gke.0
data plane version: 1.4.6-gke.0 (16 proxies)
```

*Command I Ran to Enforce Strict mTLS:*

`gcloud beta container clusters update <cluster-name> --update-addons=Istio=ENABLED \--istio-config=auth=MTLS_STRICT --zone=us-central1-a`

*I added this ServiceAccount using `kubectl apply -f`*:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: frontend-serviceaccount
---
```

To make this work, I added one line to the `spec` for the `frontend` `Deployment`, which was:

`serviceAccountName: frontend-serviceaccount`

Lastly, this is the AuthorizationPolicy I am trying to use to only permit traffic from the `frontend` to talk to the `cartservice`:

```
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: allow-cart-and-frontend-comm
 namespace: default
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: cartservice
 rules:
  - from:
    - source:
       namespaces: 
         - "default"
      # principals: ["cluster.local/ns/default/sa/frontend-serviceaccount", "frontend", "frontend-serviceaccount", "frontend-serviceaccount.default.sa.cluster.local", "/api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/frontend-serviceaccount", "frontend.default.svc.cluster.local"]
```

The `Principals` commented out above are all of the different ways I have tried to refer to the service account defined above, and neither them nor the namespace work properly - as soon as this is applied the `frontend` cannot talk to the `cartservice`.

**Results of System Debugging Calls:**
Note, these were made with the AuthPolicy applied for `principals: ["cluster.local/ns/default/sa/frontend-serviceaccount"]`.

```
$ istioctl x authz check frontend-<podID>
```

```
Checked 21/40 listeners with node IP 10.4.4.14.
LISTENER[FilterChain]     CERTIFICATE                   mTLS (MODE)          JWT (ISSUERS)     AuthZ (RULES)
0.0.0.0_80[0]             none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_80[1]             none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[0]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[1]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[2]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[3]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_3550[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_3550[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5000[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5000[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5050[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5050[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7000[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7000[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7070[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7070[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8060[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8060[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8080[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8080[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9090[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9090[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9091[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9091[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9555[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9555[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9901[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9901[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualOutbound[0]        none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualOutbound[1]        none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15004[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15004[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualInbound[0]         none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualInbound[1]         none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualInbound[2]         /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem     yes (PERMISSIVE)     no (none)         no (none)
virtualInbound[3]         none                          no (PERMISSIVE)      no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15010[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15010[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15014[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15014[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_50051[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_50051[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
10.4.4.14_8080[0]         /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem     yes (PERMISSIVE)     no (none)         no (none)
10.4.4.14_8080[1]         none                          no (PERMISSIVE)      no (none)         no (none)
10.4.4.14_15020           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
```

```
$ istioctl x authz check cartservice-69955dd686-wf5bt
```

```
Checked 21/40 listeners with node IP 10.4.5.6.
LISTENER[FilterChain]     CERTIFICATE                   mTLS (MODE)          JWT (ISSUERS)     AuthZ (RULES)
0.0.0.0_80[0]             none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_80[1]             none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[0]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[1]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[2]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_443[3]            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_3550[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_3550[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5000[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5000[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5050[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_5050[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7000[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7000[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7070[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_7070[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8060[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8060[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8080[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_8080[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9090[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9090[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9091[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9091[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9555[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9555[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9901[0]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_9901[1]           none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualOutbound[0]        none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualOutbound[1]        none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15004[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15004[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualInbound[0]         none                          no (none)            no (none)         yes (1: ns[default]-policy[allow-cart-and-frontend-comm]-rule[0])
virtualInbound[1]         none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
virtualInbound[2]         /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem     yes (PERMISSIVE)     no (none)         yes (1: ns[default]-policy[allow-cart-and-frontend-comm]-rule[0])
virtualInbound[3]         none                          no (PERMISSIVE)      no (none)         yes (1: ns[default]-policy[allow-cart-and-frontend-comm]-rule[0])
0.0.0.0_15010[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15010[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15014[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_15014[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_50051[0]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
0.0.0.0_50051[1]          none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
10.4.5.6_7070[0]          /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem     yes (PERMISSIVE)     no (none)         yes (1: ns[default]-policy[allow-cart-and-frontend-comm]-rule[0])
10.4.5.6_7070[1]          none                          no (PERMISSIVE)      no (none)         yes (1: ns[default]-policy[allow-cart-and-frontend-comm]-rule[0])
10.4.5.6_15020            none                          no (none)            no (none)         no (none)
```

Comment: What does [`istioctl experimental authz`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/#istioctl-experimental-authz) say for your `frontend` and `cartservice` pods? An `istioctl analyze` will be helpful also. Finally, the `selector` is a workload selector - can you verify whether the `cartservice`'s corresponding [workload](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/glossary/#workload) object has the label you've set?

Comment: First I would suggest to install [istio on-prem](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) instead of addon, it´s very quick and the version is a lot newer and there were a lot of changes.  About the issue I think you have to use `rules:
  - from:
    - source: principals: ["cluster.local/ns/default/sa/frontend-serviceaccount"]` instead of `rules:
  - from:
    - source:
       namespaces: 
         - "default"` . Take a look at example [here](https://istiobyexample.dev/authorization/).

Comment: @jt97 thanks, I actually have tested that and it sadly still does not work. I updated the question according. Also, I did not install Istio on-prem because my understanding is that GKE is only compatible with Istio 1.4* so I didn't see why I would. What additional tools does the on-prem distro give me access to that I don't otherwise have?  Thanks! (cite for versioning: (https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/versions))

Comment: @AkshatMahajan thanks. I have updated my post to include the output of those things! `istioctl x authz` seems to be right?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan one issue is that I cannot seem to call `istioctl analyze`, as I believe it is not in the version of Istio I am using? Further, I cannot find the workloads, as calling
`$ kubectl get workload` results in `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "workload"`

Comment: GKE is compatible with addon version 1.4.6, but you don´t need to use addon. You can install on-prem istio on your own and it´s up to date so you even if you use GKE you can install istio on-prem 1.6.6. Few examples like there is a new tool istiod which replace pilot, citadel and galley. There is no mixer since 1.5. You would have to check [upgrade notes](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/) to check every change. If you use 1.4 then you should check older [docs](https://archive.istio.io/v1.4/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/)

Comment: @jt97 thank you. How would I go about switching from a working 1.4 add-on distro to an on-prem 1.6.6?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan could this line, "Please note that the Istio on GKE add-on is not compatible with `Workload Identity`." explain it? I believe that may be the bug. (source https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing)

Comment: Do you have 2 authorization policies , 1 to deny all requests and this is the second one? or just this one you specified in your question?  About switching, if you create new gke cluster instead of switching on the addon, turn it off and download istioctl as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) and install istio as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#install). You can´t just switch from an addon to on-prem, and you can´t upgrade addon to on-prem.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I will try making the cluster again following those instructions. Thank you! And no, I only have that one `AuthorizationPolicy` for now.

Comment: @jt97 I have moved over to another cluster, and I configured Istio 1.6 to work with the Boutique example. I now have a working Istio 1.6 mesh, but sadly the ServiceAccount AuthorizationPolicy still does not work (using `principals: ["cluster.local/ns/..."]`)

Comment: @AkshatMahajan now that I am on Istio 1.6 I can use `istioctl analyze`, which returns `✔ No validation issues found when analyzing namespace: default.`

Comment: Workload corresponds to `deployment` object in this context - can you check the pods/deployments have the corresponding label set?

Comment: Like @AkshatMahajan mentioned, could you add labels from your deployment to your service-account? There is an example in [bookinfo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.6/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml) app.

Comment: Hi @AkshatMahajan. The deployment has no labels when I apply it. It selects pods with the label selector `app: frontend`, so the pods are behaving correctly, it seems.

Comment: @jt97 thanks. I just updated the service-account to have `app: frontend` in its metadata. I will try updating the deployment and will run it.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan, the `cartservice` Deployment does not have any labels. I labelled it with `app: cartservice`, but I am still getting the 500 Error. Thanks so much for the help, once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, after debugging in person with OP, we discovered that the cluster was underspecified in terms of CPU usage. On resizing the cluster to have additional CPU (1 vCPU -> 4 vCPUs), we were able to get `authz` policies working and respected.

Our hypothesis is that `istiod` was failing to respond to requests because of this issue. We do not know why.